# Unit testing in Angular: How to test the error in the get request to obtain 100% coverage

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular11

Using Angular 11 I can't test the error in the get request to obtain 100% coverage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptvZL.png)

from the oninit of the AppComponent I call the "loadNotifications" method which makes an asynchronous get call which controls both the correct and incorrect output

**app.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  private cargarNotificaciones(): void {
    this._http.get<any>(environment.API_BASE_PATH + environment.endPointNotification).subscribe(
      (data: any[]) => {
        cosole.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        this._ir.interpretarRespuesta(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

The problem is that from the tests, I am not able to go through the error and be able to have 100% coverage

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
...
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<any>;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        ...
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    injector = getTestBed();
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
  });

  it('Debería funcionar el método getNotificaciones con error', waitForAsync(() => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(app._http, 'get').and.returnValue(new Error('error 404'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const resultado = app.cargarNotificaciones();
    expect(resultado).toBe(undefined);
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`_http.get` should return an observable instead of just an Error object. You can use `throwError` or `of` from rxjs. try to do something like this:

```
  it('Debería funcionar el método getNotificaciones con error', waitForAsync(() => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(app._http, 'get').and.returnValue(throwError('error 404'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const resultado = app.cargarNotificaciones();
    expect(resultado).toBe(undefined);
  }));
```

or

```
  it('Debería funcionar el método getNotificaciones con error', waitForAsync(() => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(app._http, 'get').and.returnValue(of(new Error('error 404')));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const resultado = app.cargarNotificaciones();
    expect(resultado).toBe(undefined);
  }));
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but the following lines continue to mark me as not coverage:
`      (error) => {
        this._ir.interpretarRespuesta(error);`